# Adding more colours to attributes

Tags: attributes

I am trying to add additional colour to my attributes but when I save it won't save the additional colour.
Is there a limit or how can I increase the limit?
[image]

Comment: How many colours do you have?

Comment: Did you check your server logs?

Comment: I'm not aware of such limit. as @Sharif said, check your logs (be them Apache logs or Magento logs)

Comment: Does Magento throw you any error message? If not, there could be a good chance that something wrong on server side.

Comment: There's no error and there's around 100 colours. I'll check the server side.

Comment: [Thu Jul 23 14:27:35 2015] [error] [client 82.71.215.1] client denied by server configuration: /data02/c7630311/public_html/app/etc/local.xml

Comment: probably, you should scroll to right and see if there's a  vertical scrollbar?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a server configuration issue.
`max_input_vars` php var tels you how many post/get/cookie variables are accepted.
If you send more than that the post/get/cookie array will be empty.
Try to increase that value from `php.ini` and restart your server.

Comment: Also check .htaccess for `php_value max_input_vars` since it could override php.ini's settings